# c# string to unmanaged c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++

I need to write something like

```
switch (nameOfType) 
{
  case "burk":
    return "zzzz";
```

in my c++ DLL (I need this to compare type names)

Where nameOfType is a string that came from c# (via DLLImport)
but I am quite new in c++ - what type I must use to operate in c++ with strings the same way as it is in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest strings in C/C++ are NULL terminated character arrays. You can normally marshal a managed string from C# into a `const char*` type.

The code you posted will not work in C++. The switch statement in C++ only permits integral types as the operand. The simplest way to get what you want is repeated `if`:

```
if (strcmp(nameOfType, "burk") == 0)
   return "zzzz";
else if (strcmp(nameOfType, "xyz") == 0)
   return "yyyy";
else ...
```

If you need more string functionality, you should consider using the `std::string` class. It supports the normal searching, comparison, inserting and substring operations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `char*` in switch statements in C++ like C#. One thing you can do is replace it with an enum

```
enum StringEnum { burk , foo , bar };

map<string,StringNum> m;

m["burk"] = burk;
m["foo"]  = foo;
m["bar"]  = bar;
```

Now you can use a switch statement like below

```
StringEnum e = m[nameOfType];
switch(e)
{
  case bruk;
```

etc etc